# Is there a way to use an item without placing it on the hotbar first?

Tags: terraria

Is there a way to use an item (e.g. a mushroom to heal) in Terraria without placing it on the hotbar first? I know about the "use health potion" shortcut but I wonder if there's a general way that works for any item type (e.g. a single buff potion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click to pick it up, then click again outside your inventory. (Works with magic mirror, anyway.) Autopause needs to be turned off for this to work. In the case of tools, holding shift will automatically use the tool appropriate for the type of object your cursor is over.

Comment: I haven't played Terraria in a while, but doesn't this just drop most things?

Comment: Yeah, seems to drop the items.

Comment: I think right click uses it left drops it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I upvoted this answer because it's what mine would have been... are you playing on an old version or something? (Also, I believe this doesn't work if you have the inventory autopause thing on.)

Comment: True, might actually be related to the autopause thing...

Comment: @Vince: Please edit your answer to include that autopause needs to be disabled. Then I'll upvote it (right now the downvote is locked in until you edit it)

Comment: With tools hold shift and hover over desired item(example: hover over stone to use pick, hover over wood to use axe, etc)

Comment: @ThiefMaster you are allowed to edit other people's posts, you know.

Comment: Yes I do (obviously :p). But with an "active" answerer I usually prefer him to include something that came up in the comments. And after my comment I didn't really look at this post anymore so I never noticed him "abandoning" his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use H for health potion, M for mana potion and B for all buff potions. It will use the first item available, starting from the hotbar and moving from left to right, top to bottom. Except with Buffs, which it will drink all available (though not entire stack, only one per stack)

So if you have an Ironskin Potion and Spelunker Potion and use B, it will drink both Ironskin potion and Spelunker Potion.

If you have Lesser Health Potion before your Greater Health Potion, it will use LHP first. Learned this one the hard way while fighting Destroyer.

Comment: B will drink *all* buff potions